# sql syntax using mysql which will return in cyclic order till last records

Tags: mysql, sql, database

data stored in table

```
ID | STORE     | PRODUCT | PRICE
--------------------------------
1  | fliplart  | Mobile  | 20
2  | fliplart  | x-box   | 30
3  | fliplart  | TV      | 10
4  | amazon    | Watch   | 15
5  | amazon    | x-box   | 30
6  | ebay      | TV      | 10
7  | ebay      | Watch   | 15
8  | ebay      | x-box   | 30
9  | ebay      | x-box   | 30
10 | shopclues | TV      | 10
11 | jabong    | Watch   | 15
```

want data in cyclic orderby store as shown below

```
ID | STORE     | PRODUCT | PRICE
--------------------------------
1  | fliplart  | Mobile  | 20
4  | amazon    | Watch   | 15
6  | ebay      | TV      | 10
9  | shopclues | TV      | 10
10 | jabong    | Watch   | 15
2  | fliplart  | x-box   | 30
5  | amazon    | x-box   | 30
7  | ebay      | Watch   | 15
3  | fliplart  | TV      | 10
8  | ebay      | x-box   | 30
9  | ebay      | x-box   | 30
```

Please help in getting records as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get what you want by adding a "row number" for each value and then sorting by that:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@s = store, @rn + 1,
                        if(@s := store, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from table t cross join
           (select @s := '', @rn := 0) vars
      order by store, id
     ) t
order by rn, store;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon it works but the sequence is not what i posted but that i will manage by changing order by clause on columns.

Also can you please explain me this query. I appreciate if you explain me so that in future i can also do this by myself.

Comment: @AmrishKhatri . . . The subquery enumerates the rows for each `store`.  Run the subquery, and look at the results.  If you don't understand the use of variables in MySQL queries, then refer to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon i tried and got it, i will also try to understand variables in MySQL for future refrence.